# The Application object is being shut down как решить?

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть метод который срабатывает при нажатии кнопки.Он использует конструкцию async await.

```
    private async  void OkButton(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            //какая-то логика.
            for (int i = 0; i < ListOfFiles.Length; i++)
            {
                //какая-то логика.
                Window window=new Window();
                window.Show();
                await sem.WaitAsync();//где sem это SemaphoreSlim для того ,чтобы цикл не продолжал открывать новое окно,пока не закроется старое.
               //какая-то логика.
            }
    }
```

Так вот при закрытии MainWindow,когда Window открыт.Выбрасывается exception The Application object is being shut down.
Пробовал подписать метод на событие MainWindow.Closed,который:

```
 private void window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        window.Close();
        App.Current.Shutdown();
    }
```

Но не помогло,при отладке выяснилось,что даже после вызове метода         App.Current.Shutdown();.Метод OkButton продолжает работать,и при создании нового окна,так как приложение завершило работу,в конструкторе окна Window при вызове метода InitializeCompponent() высвечивается данная ошибка.Также я пробовал
в App.xaml  проинициализировать следующее свойство,следующим значением  ShutdownMode="OnExplicitShutdown",но это не помогло.Конечно я могу создать булевскую переменную и если она равна false,не создавать в цикле for окно.Но мне хотелось бы понять почему так происходит,и как это адекватно можно решить.И да при использовании метода,без оператора async,всё нормально.

Привожу Stack Trace из исключения.Где AskReplace.xaml окно window,которое создаётся в цикле.

at System.Windows.Application.GetResourcePackage(Uri packageUri)
   at System.Windows.Application.GetResourceOrContentPart(Uri uri)
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at MusicSorter.AskReplace.InitializeComponent() in D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\MusicSorter\MusicSorter\AskReplace.xaml:line 1
   at MusicSorter.AskReplace..ctor(String userFileToReplace, Button buttonToCancel) in D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\MusicSorter\MusicSorter\AskReplace.xaml.cs:line 59
   at MusicSorter.MainWindow.CopyFile(String from, String to) in D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\MusicSorter\MusicSorter\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 218
   at MusicSorter.MainWindow.d__10.MoveNext() in D:\Leva\Work\Informatika\CSharp\My OPENSOURCE projects\MusicSorter\MusicSorter\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 181

Comment: А почему `OnExplicitShutdown` не помогло? Должно было по идее помочь. Что происходит в этом случае?

Comment: И ещё, приведите stack trace из исключения.

Comment: При использовании OnExplicitShutdown тот же Exception "The Application object is being shut down".

Comment: А когда вы вызываете `Shutdown`? Если после этого вы открываете окно, то конечно плохо, приложение уже «умерло». Вы должны по идее вызывать `Shutdown` только когда уверены, что больше окон вам не нужно.

Comment: Shutdown я запускаю в методе,которое подписано на событие MainWindow.Closed.То есть когда MainWindow закрывается,вызывается метод,в котором я запускаю Shutdown.И по идее метод OkButton должен тоже оборваться,и не завершать итерацию цикла.Но он её завершает,создавая новое окно и выбрасывая исключение.Если я не использую async await,то всё нормально.При вызове Shutdown метод OkButton обрывается,и окна закрываются без вышеуказанного исключения.

Comment: А как выглядит синхронная версия функции? Странно. В любом случае, показывать окно после `Application.Shutdown` — это ошибка. Я бы не надеялся на то, что метод оборвётся автоматически, а обеспечил завершение этого метода до `Shutdown`.